# javascript crash when call getElementById for a not defined input id

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This is an example code.
I expected to receive an alert with "undefined", instead the script crash.
How can I make it work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<!-- <input type="text" id="demo"></input> -->

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var message = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    if ( message ) alert (message);
     else alert ("undefined");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is the input field commented? Because that is kind of your problem here..

Comment: change your if  loop if(typeof variable_here === 'undefined'){
    // your code here.
};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check below code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<!-- <input type="text" id="demo"></input> -->

<script>
function myFunction() {
   if (document.getElementById("demo"))
     var message = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    if ( message ) alert (message);
     else alert ("undefined");

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you can't read the property `value` from `null`. `getElementById` returns `null` if the element isn't found. So you need to guard against that:

```
var element = document.getElementById("demo");
var message = element && element.value;
if (message !== null) {
    alert(message);
} else {
    alert("undefined");
}
```

`message` will be `null` if the element doesn't exist, or the element's `value` (which may be `""`) if it does.

Or alternately without `message`:

```
var element = document.getElementById("demo");
if (element) {
    alert(element.value);
} else {
    alert("undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<!-- <input type="text" id="demo"></input> -->

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var message = undefined
    if (document.getElementById("demo"))
     message = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    if ( message ) alert (message);
     else alert ("undefined");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `document.getElementById("demo")` is `null` in this case, so there is no property `value` of null. That's where your script breaks.

Try putting

```
var message = document.getElementById("demo") && document.getElementById("demo").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an alert with "undefined" if your code was:

```
var message = document.getElementById("demo");
```

since no element exists with such id.

But it is an error to try to access a member of non-existent element.